# Is there a VirtualBox guest command to determine interface type?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Is it possible for a guest to determine the an interface type (i.e., whether eth0 is NAT, host only, bridged or internal)?

Something to be run from the guest like this:

guest-vm ~# vbox-interface eth0

eth0 is a NAT interface.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to what you are looking for is [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) and it unfortunately does not offer that functionality. Guest Additions will give the host the ability to interact with guest through a variety of APIs and utilities but I don't think there is anyway for guest to query the host for information about the "hardware" that VirtualBox presents to it.